# Matching number of occurrences skipping chars

Tags: regex, pcre

I am attempted to match a pattern that is three `y` bordered by a number on both sides:

```
1yyy5
```

with the above example this works:

```
\d{1}y{3}\d{1}
```

Now if I add an additional char between one of the `y`, it fails:

`1yyay5`

**How can I use `{}` (or somethting else?) to match occurrences between the single digits even if they are not  in consecutive order? There can be an infinite amount of chars between the two numbers, just as long as there exist exactly three `y` in between**

Desired outcome:

```
 1yyy5 //should match because three y between 2 numbers  

 1yyaaay5 // should match because there are three y between two numbers 

 3..!y3777 // would fail, only one y

 ..@#9naymnymmmyptjr8 // pass, there are exactly 3 y between 9 and 8

 1yyyy2  /fail, 1 to many y. must be exactly 3
```

Comment: Could you give more test cases? What about `1yyyy2` or `1aybycyd2` or `123,:;y!:;y&~#yX456` ?

Comment: Try `\d(?:y[^y\s]*){3}\d` but care that this also matches `1yy23y1`. It depends on your interpretation of *even if they are not consecutive*. To prevent matching it you may want to go with `\d(?:y[^y\s\d]*){3}\d` or `\d(?:y[a-xz]*){3}\d`

Comment: Edited question to add more examples and clarify a abit (or attempt to), although looks like @AhmedAbdelhameed's example may satisfy

Comment: @Kisaragi No, it doesn't. It will match four or more `y`s and that's why I deleted it. Check Toto's answer below or revo's comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one does the job:

```
\d(?:[^y\d]*y){3}[^y\d]*\d
```

**Explanation:**

```
\d          # a digit.
(?:         # start non capture group.
  [^y\d]*   # 0 or more non y or digit.
  y         # 1 y.
){3}        # end group, must appear 3 times.
[^y\d]*     # 0 or more non y or digit.
\d          # a digit.
```

Comment: Should newline characters be allowed?

Comment: @revo: I don't know, but it's easy to add them in the negated character class.

Comment: I don't know either. If OP didn't clear so should we ask.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as well!